# How to truncate string in Urdu language

Tags: vb.net, urdu

I have a function that truncate a string after givin lenght ,

```
Public Shared Function StringTruncate(ByVal strArg As String, ByVal len As String) As String

            If Trim(strArg).Length > len Then
                Return Left(strArg, len) & "..."
            Else
                Return strArg
            End If
        End Function
```

thats work fine when I use English language,but when I switched to Urdu by changing globalization setting in window,then it does not work expectedly,like in the following picture,I want (...) on opposite side.
[image: urdupic]

[image]

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage` you will need to change this in order for it to truncate successfully

Comment: What if we using this in web form,will this available there?

Comment: shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

After one day struggle I have found js and C# solution of language detection problem. Here is the code through which we can check any language that user input in the field.

```
LanguageDetector ld = new LanguageDetector();
string lanCode = ld.Detect("this is an example text in english");
if (lanCode == null) throw new Exception("Cannot detect language");
string languageNaturalName = ld.GetLanguageNameByCode(lanCode); //returns "English" for language code "en"
```

Here are the links that can be helpful to other like me.
[js supported](https://richtr.github.io/guessLanguage.js/)
this is for
 [c# code](https://idsyst.hu/development/language_detector.html)